# Problem with delphi tdbrichedit

Tags: delphi

I'm using the TDBRichEdit.
I got a table with some records, some of there are RTF formatted, some are plaintext.

I've also got a DBGrid. The grid and the dbrichedit has the same datasource.

When I click on a record on the grid which has RTF formatting, then the text is displayed formatted in the dbrichedit.
But when I click on a record which has unformatted text, it's displayed in the dbrichedit with the formatting of the old (previuosly displayed) record - but it should be displayed unformatted as it is.
How could I do this?

Comment: How are you loading the TDbRichEdit?   Do you have it tied to a TDataSource and a TField, or are you manually loading it?  I only ask because your previous attempts seem to point to using a manual method.

Comment: Yes, it's tied to a TDataSource and a TField...

Answer (score 1):

Set

```
DBRichedit1.PlainText:= true;
```

When changing to the plaintext field.